# import StdDraw java package

Tags: java, import

I would like to import this package: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/StdDraw.java.html (there is an stdlib.jar what contains StdDraw besides lots of other)
I tried 'import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw', and of course I added it to the Build Path, but I still got 'The import edu cannot be resolved'. Is there any known solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered copying and pasting all of the code into a single class? It looks to be just one class (StdDraw.java). Make a class in whatever place you want, and put the code into it.

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what I did finally, but it would be nice, if the import could work. (And this one class also depends further 4 class in the .jar, so actually I had to copy + paste these too)